# Azure Alert when a new resource is added/modified uppon a specific tag

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-monitoring, alerts, azure-alerts

We control our billings by a specific tag, for example: "Product_A", sometimes other teams are tagging resources incorrectly with our tag.

Is there a way to have an alert on Azure that send a notification when a new resource is added or modified in a resource group uppon our tag?

I'm open to others options.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Alert when a new resource is added/modified upon a specific tag: -

After a workaround on your requirement, I found few approaches, one of which is shown below to set up an alert rule conditionally.

In the Portal, create a `log analytics workspace` and browse to `Logs` on the left blade view. When you click on it, a query editor opens, which is used to retrieve the logs. I performed the query below as per the request you provided, and it was successful.

```bash
AzureActivity
| where ResourceGroup contains "xxxxx"
| where Properties contains "tags" and OperationName contains "Create" and OperationName contains "update"
| extend tags = tostring(parse_json(Properties).requestbody)
| where tags contains "CreatedDate" //Modify tag name as per your requirement
```

After that, go to `New Alert rule` to create an alert rule using the custom log search shown below.

[image]

Now, in the create rule, enter the required values and settings (for example, `threshold`etc..) and create a rule accordingly.

[image]

Alert rule is created after all the above steps.

[image]

*Another approach:*

You can also ARM template creating an action group with an email target and enables all health notifications and it is clearly detailed in [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/advisor/advisor-alerts-arm.md) with the sample template.